# $\binom{n - 1 + k}{k}$ as the basis for a polynomial vector space, and the use of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$ to derive generating functions for $a_n = n^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, vector-spaces, generating-functions

I am trying to understand the following passage from my course notes:

> [image]
> [image]

Here is Lemma 3.1:

> [image]

**Discussion:**

Starting from the beginning, I will try to explain in detail what I think I understand and ask questions where I am confused, and hopefully someone can set me straight.

**(One)** Where it says "generating funtions... of the form...", what is happening more precisely is that we are operating in some ring $R$, and the generating function $a_0 + a_1x + \dots$ is an element of the formal power series ring $R[[X]]$.

**(Two)** The "of the form $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$" part means that when following the standard multiplication rules for $R[[X]]$, we get that $(a_0 + a_1x + \dots)(1-x)^n = 1$. (I should also say that $(1 - x)^n$ is an element in $R[[X]]$ as well.)

**(Three)** Lemma 3.1 shows that $a_k = \binom{n - 1 + k}{k}$, so we know the explicit form of $a_0 + a_1x + \dots$. Algebraic manipulation of $\binom{n - 1 + k}{k}$ into $\frac{1}{(n - 1)!}(k + 1)^{(n - 1)}$ is straightforward.

**(Four)** In the above notes, we are considering $R = \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, so that means $R$ is a field, and we can therefore consider the vector space $R[X]$ over $R$ where we define scalar multiplication in the form $R \times R[X] \to R[X], (\lambda, p) \to \lambda p$, meaning that the formal power series $b_0 + b_1x + \dots \in R[X]$ multiplied by $\lambda \in R$ becomes $\lambda b_0 + \lambda b_1 x + \dots$.

**(Five)** In our polynomial vector space $V := R[X]$, we are told that $B := \bigl\{ \frac{1}{(n - 1)!}(x + 1)^{(n - 1)}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots \bigr\}$ are a basis, so we must have $\text{span}(B) = V$. I'm not sure how to show this. I suppose I can show linear independence by taking a finite subset of $B$, call them $v_1, \dots, v_m$, and noting that $\lambda_1 v_1 + \dots + \lambda_m v_m$ is a polynomial of degree equal to the highest degree of the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m$. If this linear combination equals $0 \in R[X]$, then we must have all $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_m = 0 \in R$.

I need to show that $\text{span}(B) = V$ but I am not sure how to do this. I need to show that the intersection of all subspaces $U \subseteq V$ such that $B \subseteq U$ is equal to $V$ itself.

I guess I could suppose that $\text{span}(B) \neq V$, which would mean there were some element $v \in V$ that was not in the intersection of all such $U$. Therefore there is some $U^*$ in the intersection that does not contain $v$.

I want to show that this is a contradiction, meaning that I can create $v$ out of a linear combination of the basis elements in $B$, which will imply that $v \in U^*$, which will prove that $\text{span}(B) = V$.

If $v = c_0 + c_1x + \dots + c_r x^r$, then take the set $b := \bigl\{ \frac{1}{(n - 1)!}(x + 1)^{(n - 1)}$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots r \bigr\}$. This is a finite subset of the basis $B$, so we must have $b \subseteq U^*$.

If $b_i = \frac{1}{(i - 1)!}(x + 1)^{(i - 1)}$ for $i = 1, \dots, r$, then if I pick the right scalars $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_r$ I should be able to show that $\lambda_1 b_1 + \dots + \lambda_r b_r = v$. Figuring out the right scalars seems very messy, though. **Is there any easy way to find the right scalars?**

**(Six)** Assuming that $B$ is a basis for $V$, I think then notes are trying to explain how we can use this to find the generating function for a sequence defined by $a_n = n^k$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ and fixed natural number $k$.

(Note: I think that strictly speaking the generating function for such a sequence will simply be $0^k + 1^k x + 2^k x + \dots$. What the notes really mean is that we can find the compact i.e. finite representation for this
generating function, much like how Lemma 3.1 shows that $\binom{0 + n - 1}{0} + \binom{1 + n - 1}{1}x + \dots = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^n}$.)

**I don't understand** the connection between $a_n = n^k, b_n = \binom{n - 1 + k}{k}$ and $\frac{1}{(1 - x)^k} = b_0 + b_1x + \dots$. Why $n^k$? I guess the idea is that we can write $0^k + 1^k x + 2^k x + \dots$ as a linear combination of terms $\binom{n - 1 + k}{k}$?

**(Seven)** Regarding the final paragraph concerning complex numbers, first of all I don't understand the substitution $y = cx$ when there no $y$ to be found anywhere. Are we supposed to be looking at $\binom{0 + n - 1}{0} + \binom{1 + n - 1}{1}y + \dots = \frac{1}{(1 - y)^n}$ and simply replace $y$ with $cx$ for $c \in \mathbb C$? Then we are supposed to be able to write $0^k + 1^k cx + 2^k c^2 x + \dots$ as a linear combination of terms $\binom{n - 1 + k}{k}c^n$? Since I can't understand the simpler instance in **(Six)** I don't think I can understand this part either.

---

Sorry about the length of this post. I appreciate any feedback.

---

**Edit:**

I think where I wrote $\binom{0 + n - 1}{0} + \binom{1 + n - 1}{1}y + \dots = \frac{1}{(1 - y)^n}$ in **(Seven)**, I should have written instead $\binom{k + 0 - 1}{k} + \binom{k + 1 - 1}{k}y + \dots = \frac{1}{(1 - y)^n}$. In other words it is $k$ that is fixed here and $n$ changes for every term in the generating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first four points are fine; I’ll take your last three points in reverse order.

The last paragraph could have been written more clearly. Yes, the idea is to start with

$$\frac1{(1-y)^k}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-1+k}ky^n$$

and substitute $y=cx$, but one really might just as well work directly with $cx$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1{(1-cx)^k}&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-1+k}k(cx)^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n-1+k}kc^nx^n\,,
\end{align*}$$

so $\frac1{(1-cx)^k}$ is the generating function for the sequence $\left\langle\binom{n-1+k}kc^n:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$.

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $p_n(x)=\frac1{n!}(x+1)^{\overline{n}}$, and assume that $\{p_n(x):n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a basis for $R[x]$. For each $k\in\Bbb N$ let $q_k(x)=x^k$. Since $\deg p_n(x)=n$, there are constants $c_{k,i}$ for $i=0,\ldots,k$ such that $q_k(x)=\sum_{i=0}^kc_{k,i}p_i(x)$.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}n^kx^n&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{i=0}^kc_{k,i}p_i(n)x^n\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^kc_{k,i}\sum_{n\ge 0}p_i(n)x^n\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^kc_{k,i}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{i!}(n+1)^{\overline{i}}x^n\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^kc_{k,i}\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+i}nx^n\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{c_{k,i}}{(1-x)^{i+1}}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so that $\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{c_{k,i}}{(1-x)^{i+1}}$ is the generating function for the sequence $\langle n^k:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

Probably the easiest way to see that $\{p_n(x):n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a basis for $R[x]$ is to observe that $\deg p_n(x)=n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$; an easy induction on $k$ then shows that $q_k(x)=x^k\in\operatorname{span}\{p_n(x):n\in\Bbb N\}$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. The actual coefficients in the linear combinations are a bit messy and involve Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Professor. I am still trying to digest it. (I actually forgot about the rising factorials when I was composing my question, but I'm not sure that was the main cause of my confusion.) I have a couple questions if you don't mind. 1) Is the change in order of summation from your first line to your second line in your final math display section based only on distributivity and commutativity?

Comment: 2) Regarding arguments that a set is a basis, I am used to thinking in terms of proving linear independence and proving that the set generates the entire vector space. Is the first part of your argument (regarding the degree of $p_n(x)$) meant to imply independence of the $p_n(x)$? Is the second part of your argument meant to imply that the $p_n(x)$ generate the whole space $R[x]$ because they generate the standard basis $1, x, x^2, \dots$?

Comment: I may have another question or two as I think about this further, if you do not mind. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Novice: You’re welcome. A completely rigorous proof that the change in the order of summation is legitimate would probably also involve associativity, but commutativity and distributivity are at the heart of it. \\ Yes, the fact that the $p_n(x)$ have different degrees shows that they must be linearly independent, and the fact that the standard basis is in their span then shows that they must be a basis for $R[x]$.

Comment: Professor, if I may, I wonder if there's an error in my notes. Towards the bottom of the big screen shot I posted, it says $b_n = \binom{n - 1 + k}{k}$ and $a_n = \binom{n - 1 + k}{k}$. Specifically, the denominator exponent for the generating function is in the bottom position for the binomial notation. However if you look at the top of the screenshot, and at Lemma 3.1, it's the position index number that's in that position, i.e. $a_k = \binom{k + n - 1}{k}$. I think it is in fact supposed to be the position index, not the exponent, based on the proof of Lemma 3.1. Is that right? Thank you.

Comment: @Novice: Good catch. Yes, it should be $b_k$, and the fraction should be $\frac1{(1-x)^n}$.